# Cassandra write performance

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cassandra-2.1

We have this Cassandra cluster and would like to know if current performance is normal and what we can do to improve it.

Cluster is formed of 3 nodes located on the same datacenter with total capacity of 465GB and 2GB of Heap per node. Each node has 8 cores and 8GB or RAM. Version of different components are `cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.11.872 | DSE 4.7.4 | CQL spec 3.2.1 | Native protocol v3`

The workload is described as follows:

- Keyspace use org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy placement strategy and replication factor of 3 (this is very important for us)
- Workload consist mainly of write operations into a single table. The table schema is as follows:

  `CREATE TABLE aiceweb.records (
      process_id timeuuid,
      partition_key int,
      collected_at timestamp,
      received_at timestamp,
      value text,
      PRIMARY KEY ((process_id, partition_key), collected_at, received_at)
  ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (collected_at DESC, received_at ASC)
     AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
     AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
     AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
     AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
     AND caching = { 'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE' }
     AND comment = ''
     AND compaction = { 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy' }
     AND compression = { 'sstable_compression' : 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor' }
     AND default_time_to_live = 0
     AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE'
     AND min_index_interval = 128
     AND max_index_interval = 2048;`

Write operations come from a NodeJS based API server. The Nodejs driver provided by Datastax is used (version recently updated from 2.1.1 to 3.2.0). The code in charge of performing the write request will group write operations per Primary Key and additionally it will limit the request size to 500 INSERTs per request. The write operation is performed as a BATCH. The only options explicitly set are `prepare:true, logged:false`.

OpsCenter reflect a historial level of less than one request per second in the last year using this setup (each write request been a BATCH of up to 500 operations directed to the same table and the same partition). Write request latency has been at 1.6ms for 90% of requests for almost the entire year but lately it has increased up to more than 2.6ms for the 90% of requests. Os Load has been below 2.0 and Disk Utilization has been below 5% most of the time with few peaks at 7%. Average Heap usage has been 1.3GB the entire year with peaks at 1.6GB even though currently this peak is rising during the last month.

The problem with this setup is that API performance has been degrading the entire year. Currently the BATCH operation can take from 300ms up to more than 12s (leading to a operation timeout). In some cases the NodeJS driver report all Cassandra drivers down even when OpsCenter report all nodes alive and healthy.

Compaction Stats shows always 0 on each node and `nodetool tpstats` is showing something like:

```
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All time blocked
CounterMutationStage              0         0          10554         0                 0
ReadStage                         0         0         687567         0                 0
RequestResponseStage              0         0         767898         0                 0
MutationStage                     0         0         393407         0                 0
ReadRepairStage                   0         0            411         0                 0
GossipStage                       0         0        1314414         0                 0
CacheCleanupExecutor              0         0             48         0                 0
MigrationStage                    0         0              0         0                 0
ValidationExecutor                0         0            126         0                 0
Sampler                           0         0              0         0                 0
MemtableReclaimMemory             0         0            497         0                 0
InternalResponseStage             0         0            126         0                 0
AntiEntropyStage                  0         0            630         0                 0
MiscStage                         0         0              0         0                 0
CommitLogArchiver                 0         0              0         0                 0
MemtableFlushWriter               0         0            485         0                 0
PendingRangeCalculator            0         0              4         0                 0
MemtablePostFlush                 0         0           7879         0                 0
CompactionExecutor                0         0         263599         0                 0
AntiEntropySessions               0         0              3         0                 0
HintedHandoff                     0         0              8         0                 0

Message type           Dropped
RANGE_SLICE                  0
READ_REPAIR                  0
PAGED_RANGE                  0
BINARY                       0
READ                         0
MUTATION                     0
_TRACE                       0
REQUEST_RESPONSE             0
COUNTER_MUTATION             0
```

Any help or suggestion with this problem will be deeply appreciated. Feel free to request any other information you need to analyze it.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You are staying with same amount of requests, or the workload is growing?

Looks like the server is overloaded (maybe network).

Comment: Yes we have a constant request rate over the entire year on this setup.

Comment: Did you tried to run repair/scrub/rebuild on any node? When was the last time you've performed any of these?
Did you tried to revert nodejs driver to previous version?

Comment: I perform a full repair on the cluster the last week as a first countermeasure for the problem. What is scrub and rebuild? Yes i revert the nodejs driver back into 2.1.1 and back again without result.

Comment: scrub - will rebuild sstables / rebuild will rebuild all data by copying it from other nodes

Comment: Is possible that the CLUSTERING ORDER BY be the problem considering i'm inserting data in the ascending order of the collected_at clustering key?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to find a reproducer and run the reproducer with tracing enabled - hopefully that will help to understand what the issue is (especially if you compare it to a trace in which the latency is good).

There is an example on how to enable query tracing and retrive the output via nodejs driver examples retrieve-query-trace.js (can be found on https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver)